# Javascript-frames for comment

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frame

I thinking about using frames (or iframe) for comments, in order to load less data on load.
For example: lets say I have an article with 100 comments. I'll load only the first 10, so when the user click on page 2 i'll:

1) create new frame with 11-20 comments.

2) put the first 10 comments display none.

3) change the onclick on the "2" button to just change the frame's display to block and the others to none.

**my questions are:**

1) should i use frames or iframes for this?

2) Is this idea is good? or can it make my website too slow?

3) Can google "see" the comments that hide on the frames? (that arent in the page until i click on the right number)

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution is a really awkward way of doing things.

Allow me to present this idea instead.

First, make your website work without any JavaScript at all.  That way, your pagination buttons will lead to real content and real data.  This will make Google (and other users happy.)

Enclose the comments in a `div` or possibly a `section` element.  Choose a ID at random, I'd call it `comments.`

Then, add some JavaScript to your pagination buttons and use Ajax to go out and just the next set of comments.  Go ahead and replace `#comments` with the new content.  You can either use a separate API on your server, or you can pass it a parameter which means "just the comments, no body."

Comment: Its seems like alot of info to pass on ajax: 10 comments, 10 users, ranking for comments. Seems like much slower to me

Comment: You still have to pass the information whether you are using AJAX or not. That does not seem like a lot of data for AJAX. This is a good recommendation. In fact you can just pass the raw data only in JSON format and update your HTML template as needed.

Comment: When i'm using ajax i 1) loading the data from db 2) passing it with ajax. when im loading it from the db and thats it....